# Derive value using single xpath expression

Tags: xpath

I have an xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<library>
    <ChildEntity>
        <EntityID>9099-77-005</EntityID>
        <ChildEntity>
            <EntityID>005</EntityID>
        </ChildEntity>
            <ChildEntity>
                <CharacteristicUse>
                    <Value>
                        <ValueID>123</ValueID>
                    </Value>
                    <Value>
                        <ValueID>567</ValueID>
                    </Value>
                </CharacteristicUse>
                <CharacteristicUse>
                    <Value>
                        <ValueID>555</ValueID>
                    </Value>
                    <Value>
                        <ValueID>5677</ValueID>
                    </Value>
                </CharacteristicUse>
            </ChildEntity>
    </ChildEntity>
    <ChildEntity>
        <EntityID>8888-77-005</EntityID>
        <ChildEntity>
            <EntityID>88005</EntityID>
        </ChildEntity>
            <ChildEntity>
                <CharacteristicUse>
                    <Value>
                        <ValueID>99123</ValueID>
                    </Value>
                    <Value>
                        <ValueID>59967</ValueID>
                    </Value>
                </CharacteristicUse>
            </ChildEntity>
    </ChildEntity>
</library>
```

out of which i want to derive the tags:

```
<Value>
    <ValueID>567</ValueID>
</Value>
```

such that this will be then used to remove from the xml later on.

The logic should be such that, derive and remove the tags which has EntityID = 9099-77-005 and it should pick only that tag whose immediate sibling Value/ValueID!=123.

I am new to Xpath and so far have only been able code:

/library/ChildEntity[EntityID='9099-77-005']/ChildEntity/CharacteristicUse[Value[ValueID='123']] | /Value[ValueID!=123]

Can someone please help?

Comment: I tried using sibling to return me all sibling nodes where Value/ValueID = 123 as - "/library/ChildEntity[EntityID='9099-77-005']/ChildEntity/CharacteristicUse/Value[ValueID='123']/preceding-sibling::node() | following-sibling::node()". But no luck

Comment: I got it using "/library/ChildEntity[EntityID='9099-77-005']/ChildEntity/CharacteristicUse/Value[ValueID='123']/following-sibling::* | preceding-sibling::*"

Comment: You may consider answering your question yourself and adding a few sentences of explanation why your updated XPath expression is better than the initial attempt. This way other users can learn from it.